# Drupal, Views: header doesn't accept PHP

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

I'm using Views for some nodes, and I want to display a different View title according to which taxonomy tags are selected in my filter.

I already have taxonomy field for each node in my view. But this is not what I need.
I basically need to display all the currently filtered tags on the top of my view.

I was wondering if I can solve adding some line with php, how ?

Thanks

**Update:**
I'm now using the Views Header field in Views settings, but it only processes html code, not php, so I cannot add taxonomy terms.

Is it because of my CCK Editor settings ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header should be able to accept PHP, just change the input filter to PHP. If that input filter is not available, you'll need to enable the PHP Filter module (core, optional) first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have overridden the header for the display then make sure you have the View Preview set to the correct display.